# How to convert text data type to emailaddress data type in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql, sfmc-business-unit, data-types

I have a SourceDE with field name "Email" as a text data type, but this field has emailaddresses only.

I am writing a Query Activity in marketing cloud to tranfer the data from SourceDE to DestinationDE and wanted email addresses from Source DE to be inserted into DestinationDE which is of EmailAddress data type.

I tried using Convert & cast function to convert it as Email type, but it thrown error.

Please help me on how can we acheive this EmailAddress data type conversion in marketing cloud.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do anything to convert the data type. Just querying Data Extension A, where the email address is stored in a text field, and output the query result into Data Extension B, where same field exists as an EmailAddress field.

You should be cautious about the string length limit of a EmailAddress field, which is 255 characters. Potentially shorter than your existing text field.

Comment: Thanks. This should work.